# Visual Studio will not recognize addTagHelper in razor file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I've used @addTagHelper in previous projects in the _ViewImports for MVC and not had a problem, but now its saying that the name 'addTagHelper' does not exist in current context. This is in a WCF Service Application using MVC.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of MVC / Razor are you using?

Comment: AspNet.Razor 3.2.3 and AspNet.Mvc 5.2.3

Answer (score 1):

@Bsharp Sadly TagHelpers are only an ASP.NET Core feature and wont work in non-core versions of MVC.